# Mapping for mobile robot

Tags: matlab, image-processing, slam

I am working on mapping for mobile robot in a static environment, i was able to use SIFT to select image features from my frames and also, matched more frames to have more features. My problem is how to write Matlab codes use the image features to construct the map for the mobile robot.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Matlab
2. Load features
3. Write the code to construct the map for the mobile robot.
4. Done.

What was exactly your question?